# CSP Provider Name

Tags: c#, security, smartcard, cryptoapi

how can I get CSP provider name of my connected smartcard?

I couldn't access to registry windows so I'm find some way to achieve that information through win API.

I've already seen something about SCardGetCardTypeProviderName but it seems impossibile to find a complete example in C#.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `certutil`.

Something like this:

> c:> Certutil -csplist

It lists all CSP providers that currently exist on your PC.